# Passing list input as a single argument to starmap in Python 3.X

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-3.5

I'm fairly new to python, so I apologize in advance if there are some stupid questions in here.

I'm trying to trying to parallelize a code, and in order to keep things semi-modular I need to pass several scalar values and one list from one function to another within Pool, like so:

```
with Pool(nProcs) as p:
        out1= np.array(p.starmap(function1, product(arg1, arg2, ... argN)), dtype=object)
        T_in = [out1[0,3]]
        P_in = [out1[0,5]]
        XALL = [out1[0,6]]
        out2 = np.array(p.starmap(function2, product(P_in, T_in, ..., XALL)), dtype=object)
```

The concern is in the input to the out2 line.  Basically I am passing a combination of single values and lists.  Most of these lists are passed through product so that I can iterate on them, but I need to get one list from function1 output into function2 without having product iterate through each value (i.e. passing XALL as a "block").  Obviously, the way I have it listed above it treats XALL like any other list, but if I pop XALL out of product like so:

```
result = np.array(p.starmap(psr, [product(Ppsr_in, T_rise_list, Eff_list, T_tol, Tpsr_in), XALL]), dtype=object)
```

that also doesn't work because starmap complains that I haven't given function2 enough arguments.

How can I pass this array to function2 and have it treated as a single iterable within a given process?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As a clarification, P_in and T_in are scalar values (they could be a list as well, and in earlier versions of this code they are), but XALL is a list containing a series of values that I need to pass in to a function but do NOT want to iterate through the individual values.  Those values need to be treated as a single array, because each value in the array represents a mole fraction of a single chemical species (within the context of the overall code).  If I pass it in as just `XALL` product will treat it like any other list and treat each value as a different case to be run.  I just need this information to move from one function to another.

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by passing `XALL` as a block? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in terms of plain for loops and so on? Then perhaps we can translate it. Also why are `T_in`, `P_in`, and `XALL` all single element lists?

Comment: To clarify, 'T_in' and 'P_in' are not lists but just floats.  XALL is a list (in this case ~100 values long) that should not be iterated through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want this:

```
with Pool(nProcs) as p:
    out1= np.array(p.starmap(function1, product(arg1, arg2, ... argN)), dtype=object)
    T_in = [out1[0,3]]
    P_in = [out1[0,5]]
    XALL = [out1[0,6]]
    def function2_with_XALL(p, t, ...):
        function2(p, t, ..., XALL)
    out2 = np.array(p.starmap(function2_with_XALL, product(P_in, T_in, ...)), dtype=object)
```

If that's not it, then I insist that you explain what you want it to do by writing down for loops.

Comment: So it seems like the answer is that if I use a list of lists, i.e. [XALL], product only goes down the first level, and so seems to produce the behavior I want.  I will try your suggestion on Monday to see if it produces the same results.  In terms of pseudo-code loops, it would go something like for P_in in range(1, x), for T_in in range(1,y), do the following using XALL.